# How to generate/export a RGB raster layered over a hillshade raster based on visualisation palette in R

Tags: raster, r, rgb

I have defined my own colour palette, and written my raster as a GeoTIFF with the colour palette saved into the image using the code below.

```
col_rmp <- c('#0180FF', '#0101FF', '#01FFFF', '#01FF01', '#FFFF01', '#FF0101', '#FF01FF', '#FFFFFF')
rgb0 <- image_raster(test_raster, col = col_rmp)
raster::writeRaster(rgb0, "C:/Documents/Test.tif"), format = 'GTiff', overwrite = T)
```

I would like to layer this raster over a hillShade raster of the same data, and save this as a GeoTIFF of the RGB (i.e. a GeoTIFF with the colours baked into the image). I am able to generate a `hillShade` raster using my `test_raster` and layer my `test_raster` with my colour palette over this `hillShade` raster in a plot using the code below. I am unsure how I can write what I am seeing in the plot as a GeoTIFF (effectively an RGB image which looks the same as what is output in the code below).

```
col_rmp_with_transparency <- unikn::usecol(pal = gc_col_rmp, alpha = 0.5)
slope  = terrain(test_raster, opt = "slope", unit = "degrees")
aspect = terrain(test_raster, opt = "aspect", unit = "degrees")
hill = hillShade(slope, aspect, 40, 270)
plot(hill, col=grey(0:100/100), legend=FALSE, main='Test')
plot(test_raster, col=col_rmp_with_transparency, add=TRUE)
```